# Gesture Recognizer never fires

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, uigesturerecognizer

This is what I have

UICollectionViewController
  - UICollectionViewCell
     - UIScrollView
       - ImageView

I am trying to handle tap on imageview but never get called.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap =[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
[cell.imageView addGestureRecognizer:tap];

- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer  {
    NSLog(@"Tap");
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:[recognizer locationInView:self.collectionView]];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cell's ImageView should allow user interaction first to detect the tap. make sure you enable the user interaction with the following line.

```
[cell.imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```